# Protocol with property of type Self can only be used as generic constraint, why?

Tags: swift, generics

It is not possible to use a protocol with a property with Self as type as a type, container type, parameter.
I think I need an example where it makes sense, that the compiler can not infer the type.

#### Definitions which compile

```
internal protocol Lovable {
    var inLoveTo: Self? {
        get
    }
}

internal final class Human: Lovable {
    var inLoveTo: Human? = nil
}

internal final class Animal: Lovable {
    var inLoveTo: Animal? = nil
}

internal let thing11: Human = Human()
internal let thing12: Animal = Animal()
```

#### Not working code

But the following code makes sense to me and could work. So there have to be a case where you can not infer the type at compile time, which I can not see yet.

```
import Darwin

let thing13: Lovable = Darwin.random() % 2 == 0 ? thing11 : thing12 // So you do not know which dynamicType thing13 has at compile time, but it should be Lovable, error: mismatching types

thing13.inLoveTo // It could be Lovable

// Does not work, even though it makes sense for me, since inLoveTo adopts Lovable
internal func partner(one: Lovable) -> Lovable {
    return one.inLoveTo
}
```

What do I not see?

#### Working example where at compile time you do not know the type

```
protocol Foo {
}

final class Bar1: Foo {
    let bla: Int8 = 100
}

final class Bar2: Foo {
    let bla: Int64 = 600000
}

internal let thing21: Foo = Bar1()
internal let thing22: Foo = Bar2()
internal let thing23: Foo = Darwin.random() % 2 == 0 ? thing21 : thing22 // So you do not know which type it has at compile time
```

Comment: In the above case Foo can be described perfectly and hence is said to be a proper Type. Thats why you can type cast or assign variable to it. However, a Protocol with Self or Associated type is incomplete by itself as we dont know what is the Conformer exactly ahead of time. Hence this becomes a incomplete Type. Incomplete Types are Generics and can be used Generically but Swift being a Type safe language wont allow you to lie in terms of incomplete Type.

Comment: Basically what @kandelvijaya said. You cannot access `bla` on `thing21...thing23` so the compiler has no issues with the assignment. `bla` is now just an implementation detail. Think of it like sticking a `Bar1` or `Bar2` instance in a box. The box (the protocol) tells us what the underlying instance can do – in this case it says it doesn't do anything, so there's no types for the compiler to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Self` refers to the *runtime* type of whatever is implementing that protocol. The problem is that when you have a function that takes a `Lovable` input (or a variable with an explicit annotation of `Lovable`), you're upcasting to the abstract type `Lovable`.

By doing this you're losing the type information for what `Self` was. Was it an `Animal` or a `Human`? This is needed by the compiler in order to use the protocol as a type, as it has a property of type `Self`, which cannot be resolved. This therefore means you cannot use a protocol with `Self` or `associatedtype` requirements as an actual type, you can only ever use it as a generic constraint.

One potential solution is to change the property in your protocol to be of type `Lovable`. Now you're saying that everything that conforms to `Lovable` has a property of 'some other' `Lovable`. You now don't need to know the concrete type of whatever that 'something' is, although this will break an important relationship that you want to establish (two partners must be of the same type!)

One way to maintain this relationship (at least for your function) is to use generics. The reason why using generics works is they act as a *placeholder* for a concrete type, which is supplied to the function when you call it. Now your function input knows what `Self` is – it's whatever concrete type is supplied to the function.

You could make your `partner` function generic like so:

```
func partner<T:Lovable>(one: T) -> T? {
    return one.inLoveTo
}
```

This also guarantees that the return type of the function is of the same concrete type as the input (albeit wrapped in an optional), providing better type safety.

Unfortunately for your variable assignment, there's no real solution that doesn't involve breaking the relationship you've established (`inLoveTo` must be the same type as the class). You're trying to tie a runtime decision (`Human` or `Animal` could be assigned) to a static concrete type that's given at compile time, which cannot work.

---

As you've noted, using `Self` as a return type of a function doesn't make the protocol generic. I believe this is due to variance – as you can always pass a subclass to something that expects its superclass. Therefore as the return type of the function will match the current static type of your instance, the static type can only ever refer to a less specific type than the dynamic type of the instance. Therefore you can freely return an instance with the same dynamic type, as the static type that describes it can only be less type specific.

This behaviour is different with properties as the protocol has limited control over how they are implemented. `{get}` can be implemented as *any* kind of property, `{get set}` can be implemented as a stored or calculated property with a setter. In both of these cases, the property is potentially able to be set in the conforming class. Now we run into the original problem. `Self` is the concrete type of the class, therefore we have to know that concrete type in order to assign to it, which you lose upon upcasting.

You cannot simply treat the property as being a `Loveable` as that would allow any conforming instance to be assigned to it, i.e assigning an `Animal()` to a `Human` property – which is illegal.

Comment: @originaluser2 I can create a protocol with Self as return type and use it as a type. I do not think the compiler needs the dynamic type at compile time, because using a non generic protocol and random works, then the compiler can also not know the type. I do not need a solution, I need an explanation, why Apple did it that way.

Comment: @iGodric The compiler needs the concrete type at compile time if you want it to enforce your relationship between the instance and its property. A non-generic protocol works fine because you're not defining a relationship, you're just saying "this thing can do X, Y and Z, and that's all you need to know about it". With a generic protocol, you're saying "this thing can do X, but X is the same concrete type as the thing", so the compiler asks "what's the concrete type of the thing?", which in this case you don't know until runtime.

Comment: I added more explanation to the question. At compile time does the compiler not know in the working example which dynamic type it will have. At runtime you know the type of it. You say it cannot be resolved, that is why it does not work. But in the Foo example it cannot be resolved too, and it works.

Comment: Since you added Variance to your answer, the question remains. If the compiler sees inLoveTo is Self, it always conforms to Lovable, so it could use Lovable in all cases where the adopting class is not clear. This auto upcast (variance) does not work. Self is Lovable after all, why does the compiler not use Lovable in all cases of Self when necessary?

Comment: @iGodric The problem with properties is that the protocol has limited control over how they are implemented. `{get}` can be implemented as *any* kind of property, `{get set}` can be implemented as a stored or calculated property with a setter. In both of these cases, the property is potentially able to be set in the conforming class. Now we run into the original problem. `Self` is concrete type of the class, therefore we *have* to know that concrete type in order to assign to it, which you lose upon upcasting. Otherwise you could assign an `Animal()` to a `Human` property.

Comment: Eureka! ASSIGNMENT that is it! Because of get I did not thought about that it could still be set, even though you said that the types of two partners must be the same could give me the idea. It is not allowed because I could set the wrong type! Thank you so much, now I can sleep peacefully.

Comment: @iGodric Glad we got there in the end! Happy to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

Lets go one by one:

```
 let thing13: Lovable = Darwin.random() % 2 == 0 ? thing11 : thing12
```

In this case, it makes sense for us as a reader. But there is a shortcoming?  First, even a static assignment wont compile like you do.

```
 let thing13: Lovable = thing11
```

There is a deeper meaning why not. However, thinking in this way might make sense to get started. When the compiler sees this code, it will try to cast thing11 to a type `Lovable`. Casting is eventually specifying how many bits make up this data structure. For example:

```
 int b = 10;
 char greeting[] = (char[]) b; //C
```

Doing so you specify a int [8 bit long] to a array of [8 bit long] chars ==> String. The string however might not be useful as it might contain garbage.

This takes us to another thing. Lovable cannot be defined alone to say how big the memory bits it will take and what will be the structure of the memory for the properties it might have. We will not know the offset, we wont know if this is a value type or a reference type. And In essence, the memory structure is not complete. The type is said to be `Generic Type.`

And this is why you cant assign a concrete value [bits] to a structure/type which is not completely defined in isolation.

However, this is my reasoning and im not a compiler guy. If there is a proper explanation, please do comment below. Even If this doesn't make sense, i tried my best.

Comment: Added more explanation to the question: At compile time the compiler does not know how much space he has to allocate for thing23. But there is not a problem there.

Answer (score 1):

@originalUser2 described it well above.  Here is a way to implement what I think you were asking, buy giving the `Human` and `Animal` some other behavior (`protocol`) in common.  Maybe this example will help you see it?

```
internal protocol Lovable {
  var inLoveTo: LivingThing? { get }
}

extension Lovable {
  func partner() -> LivingThing? {
    return inLoveTo
  }
}

protocol LivingThing {
  var name: String? { get }
}

internal final class Human: LivingThing, Lovable {
  var inLoveTo: LivingThing? = nil
  var name: String?
}

internal final class Animal: LivingThing, Lovable {
  var inLoveTo: LivingThing? = nil
  var name: String?
}

internal let thing11 = Human()
thing11.name = "Wilson"
internal let thing12 = Animal()
thing12.name = "Fido"
internal let thing13 = Human()

thing13.inLoveTo = thing11
print(thing13.partner()?.name)  // "Wilson"
thing13.inLoveTo = thing12
print(thing13.partner()?.name)  // "Fido"
```

Comment: That is not helpful at all. I know what works. The question is why does Apple not allow it to work with Self ?